# Auto refresh/calling of yii controller action

Tags: iphone, yii-extensions, yii

In a Yii application controller I have an action used for xml url parsing and insertion into a database table.

After a certain time interval I want to check if there were any updates in the xml url. I want to achieve this by calling the controller action again.

I want to achieve this by automatically refreshing the page or call the controller action automatically. What would be the best way in Yii to accomplish what I want?

Comment: you want to call controller action from view file or from  another controller action?

Comment: no. Automatically call a controller action.

Comment: make a ajax call by jquery set interval from main layout of your application to controller action and display data wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a cron job that calls a Yii action. Since cron jobs call actions from the command line, you should write them as console actions. Check [Yii guide on Console Applications](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console)